# Can't get MethodInfo instance in reflection-only context

Tags: c#, .net, system.reflection

The following code shows method's name correctly:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    try
    {
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1");
        foreach (var referencedAssembly in assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies())
        {
            Assembly.Load(referencedAssembly.Name);
        }
        Type bl1Type = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Bl1");
        var types = new[] {typeof(MyEnum) };
        var method = bl1Type.GetMethod("Method1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, Type.DefaultBinder, types, null);
        Console.WriteLine(method == null ? "Method was null" : $"Found {method.Name}");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

But if I try to resolve Method1 in a reflection-only context to improve performance and change the call to `Assembly.Load("ClassLibrary1");` with `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("ClassLibrary1");` then `method` is always null and don't get resolved. Any ideas about how to resolve a method in a reflection-only context?

Comment: Are there any dependent assemblies in the mix?

Comment: @Slugart The solution is very simple, it has 3 projects, one dll only contains an enumtype, the second a public class with two methods, one of the receives the enum type as parameter. The first thing I do is load all dependan assemblies so I don't think the problems is there..  Here is the whole code: https://github.com/oacostam/ReflectionTest 
I know there are several restrictions in reflection-only context, is this a bug a just one of those restrictions?

Comment: When you do your reflection only test are you calling `Assembly.Load(referencedAssembly.Name);` or `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(referencedAssembly.Name);`?

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Per my tests, if assembly is loaded in reflection-only context, it doesn't matter how you load references. I tried both, what makes the difference is how you load the main assembly. If you just call Load(), then method is not null, otherwise calling ReflectionOnlyLoad() renders it null.

Comment: First thing I did is look at the `<ProjectTypeGuids>` in the .csproj files to see what kind of project type was being used.  Eek!!  There are none.  There has to be a relevant story behind that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you try the following you will see that your method is found in the list

```
var methods = bl1Type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
```

Also,if you search for the method that accepts the string parameter it will also work

```
var types = new[] {typeof(string)};
```

I think it's confused by the MyEnum.
If you load the MyEnum from the second dll it will work

```
Assembly assembly2 = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("ClassLibrary2");
Type bl2Type = assembly2.GetType("ClassLibrary2.MyEnum");
var types = new[] { bl2Type };
```

The full code

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace ReflectionTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad("ClassLibrary1");
            Type bl1Type = assembly.GetType("ClassLibrary1.Bl1");
            var types = new[] { Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad(assembly.GetReferencedAssemblies().Single(a => a.Name == "ClassLibrary2").Name).GetType("ClassLibrary2.MyEnum") };
            //var types = new[] {typeof(MyEnum)}; //doesn't work
            var method = bl1Type.GetMethod("Method1", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public, Type.DefaultBinder, types, null);
            Console.WriteLine(method == null ? "Method was null" : $"Found {method.Name}");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

So,your initial code doesn't work because it tries to find a method that uses a different "MyEnum" (and of course it doesn't exist)

Answer (score 1):

ReflectionOnly context is separate loader context from the regular loader context. It loads own copy of the assemblies and types, the system types from mscorlib are shared with the regular loader context though.

Also, there is typically no performance advantage in loading assemblies into ReflectionOnly context. ReflectionOnly context uses the exact same loading mechanism as regular assemblies, except that attempt to execute any code from them is blocked and a few sanity checks are suppressed (https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/junfeng/2004/08/24/reflection-only-assembly-loading/ describes the details).